# layouts in expressjs

Tags: layout, node.js, express

I want to use 2 layouts for main page and admin page

 What should i configure my code to do that? 

 here is my current code configure

```
app.configure(function(){
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: 'secrect', store: MemStore({
  reapInterval: 60000 * 10
})}));
app.use(app.router);
});
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I usually set layout to false globally, so I know exactly what layout I use where (so no default layout):

```
app.set('view options', { layout: false });
```

Then in my routes I can set a layout per route like so:

```
res.render('my_page', { layout: 'my_layout' });
```

Read more [about Express layouts and templates engines](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

Comment: expressjs.com link no longer goes to layout.

Comment: Here's the layout docs for 2.X http://expressjs.com/2x/guide.html#view-rendering.  It looks like layouts disappeared in 3.X and were replaced by includes? https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/ejs/views/users.html

Comment: For express 3.x Layout & Partial support check out  https://github.com/publicclass/express-partials

Comment: Actually I can't find any page saying about rendering on epxressjs.com now, document is simple and hard to find information. Do they want all us use their training services? :)

Comment: Exactly what I needed