# How to get different css files for different routes (express, node.js)

Tags: node.js, express

I have such a directory content

```
app\
  app.js
html-views\
  corporate\
    css\main.css            //css.corp
    index.html
  ecommerce\
    css\main.css            //css.ecom
    index.html
```

I`m trying to config two routes:

```
var sys = require( "sys" );
var express = require("express");
var cons = require("consolidate");
var app = express();
app.engine("html",cons.swig);
app.set("view engine","html");
app.set("views","../html-views/");

//HERE I HAVE TO CONFIGURE CSS

app.get("/corporate",function(request,response){
response.render("corporate/index");
});
app.get("/ecommerce",function(request,response){
response.render("ecommerce/index");
});
app.listen(8080);
```

I want to configure choosing "main.css" depending to the route, but i can`t

If I write:

```
app.use("/css",express.static("../html-views/corporate/css"));
app.use("/css",express.static("../html-views/ecommerce/css"));
```

then one css will override another.

If I write:

```
app.get("/corporate",function(request,response){
    app.use("/css",express.static("../html-views/corporate/css"));
    response.render("corporate/index");
});
```

then they override each other only once.

How should I write? Thanks for your attantion.

Comment: Can you not have 2x app.js?

Comment: What about prefixing your `/css` in the two `app.use()`s with `/corporate` and `/ecommerce`? No more conflicts.

Comment: trying to do without changing .html (where src="css/main.css")

Comment: Connect vhosts might be what you are after http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/vhost.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason that you don't use template engine? Handlebars with `layout` option can solve this easily.

I found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790999/1822805

Comment: For now the question is a bit outdated)
I guess, your solution can work.

Comment: app.get("/corporate",function(request,response){
    response.render("/index",{cssOption:'corporate'}); 
    });

Comment: Lol I did not check the date. Glad to know you! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to solve the same issue as following:

In the ecommerce.html,I include the css file for this template like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/ecommerce.css">
```

So in this way, different routes include different css for specific template.

Hope this will you help you.

Cheers